# Jquery DataTable is not working properly in Angular 4 Application

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables

I am using Jquery DataTable in Angular 4 application. During reload the grid Paging option is not working properly. Iam using the below code in Typescript

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
  $('#Appointment').DataTable();
}, 1000);}

SearchAppointment() {
var param = {
  "Hcp_Id": this.Appointment.Hcp_Id,
  "Cons_Id": this.Appointment.Cons_Id,
  "Sp_Id": this.Appointment.Sp_Id,
  "FromDate": this.Appointment.FromDate,
  "ToDate": this.Appointment.ToDate
};
this.JsonApiService.CommonService('Appointment/GetAppointmentSearch', this.JsonApiService.encrypt(JSON.stringify(param)).toString()).subscribe((Resp) => {
  this.AppointmentList = this.JsonApiService.decrypt(Resp);
});  }
```

Html code is

```
<table id="Appointment" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th> Date</th>
              <th> Time</th>
              <th> Patient</th>
              <th> Consultant</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let Appointments of AppointmentList ">
              <td>{{Appointments.CA_Date}} </td>
              <td>{{Appointments.CA_Time}} </td>
              <td>{{Appointments.CA_App_Name}} </td>
              <td>{{Appointments.Cons_Name}} </td>                  
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

When loading the page grid is working properly (Refer image1). If I click Search button to reload the grid then paging option is not working (Refer image2). 
Image2 
[image]

Image2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each time you update your AppointmentList, you should destroy and reapply the DataTable.

When you apply the DataTable via `$('#Appointment').DataTable();`, the DataTables component will parse all of the `<tr>` elements into its own internal data data structure, which is how it can page/sort/filter.

When you replace the table html by updating your AppointmentList, you break DataTable's hold on the html table rows.

So, when you search, destroy the previous DataTable instance, perform your search, and then reapply the DataTable.

You can destroy the datatable by saving a reference to it when applying, like so:

`let datatable = $('#Appointment').DataTable();`

then later you can call

`datatable.destroy();`